# How to print ordered prdouct images in woocommece pdf invoices plugin

Tags: php, html, pdf, woocommerce, invoice

I have an woocommerce site. I need to print product images on my generated pdf invoice. I don't want to buy premium plugin. I just want to simply print the product image in the invoice using foreachloop. But I dont have any plugin development skill. Is there any way to print product images in the invoice?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

To show the product image you can try to use the following code, which you must add directly in the pdf invoice file template just below the product name.

```
<div class="product-img"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() ); ?> " width="100" height="100" /></div>
```